# Run a helm command from a running helm session?

Tags: helm

It seems by default this can't be done. For example, if I try to activate `helm-mini`, and then from there activate `helm-M-x`, I get the error message: `Error: Trying to run helm within a running helm session`. Is there a good way around this constraint when writing a custom function?

My use case is this: I am trying to write my own function that will try to call `helm-mini`, but if helm is already running (i.e., if `helm-alive-p` evaluates to `t`) it will run `helm-projectile-find-file` instead. What I have so far is:

```el
(defun es/helm-mini-or-projectile-find-file ()
  (interactive)
  (if (not (helm-alive-p))
      (helm-mini)
    (progn (helm-keyboard-quit)
           (helm-projectile-find-file))))
```

I am trying to kill helm if it is running before calling `helm-projectile-find-file`, because, as mentioned above, I can't run a helm command if I am already in the middle of another helm command. However, it seems like `helm-keyboard-quit` breaks out of the function before `helm-projectile-find-file` is executed. Or perhaps there is something else wrong with my code. I am still not very proficient at all with emacs lisp. Is there a good way to get around the constraint of no helm commands during a running helm session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (helm-run-after-exit FUNCTION &rest ARGS)

`helm-run-after-exit` exits current helm session, and then runs FUNCTION, so this is what you want:

```el
(defun es/helm-mini-or-projectile-find-file ()
  (interactive)
  (if (helm-alive-p)
      (helm-run-after-exit #'helm-projectile-find-file)
    (helm-mini)))
```

To call this command from a helm session, you need to bind a key to it since you can't use `helm-M-x`, e.g.,

```el
(bind-key "C-c C-p" #'es/helm-mini-or-projectile-find-file)
```

---

Similarly, if you want to use `helm-M-x` from arbitrary helm commands, you can wrap `helm-M-x` with a new command and assign a key from `helm-map` to it.

```el
(defun my-helm-M-x ()
  (interactive)
  (with-helm-alive-p
    (helm-run-after-exit
     (lambda () (call-interactively #'helm-M-x)))))

(bind-key "M-x" #'my-helm-M-x helm-map)
```